# Can I freeze fresh hyssop?

Tags: freezing, herbs

Is it possible to freeze fresh hyssop? Can I expect it to be as aromatic and flavorful after defrosting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the answer for most leafy herbs is yes, fragance and flavor is preserved. Never tryed hyssop, however [Gardening Know How](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/herbs/hyssop/growing-hyssop-plant.htm) site says it freezes fine:

> it can be dried or frozen and stored for later use. When harvesting a hyssop plant, cut it in the morning hours once any dew has dried. Hang the plants upside down in small bunches to dry in a dark, well-ventilated area. Alternatively, you can place the leaves in a plastic bag after removing them from the stems and place in the freezer until ready to use.

Answer (score 2):

The aromatics diminish. I've tried this, with hyssop - because I have a bunch of bulk spices.  I've found that an airtight jar in a dark/cool cabinet is best, even for an extended period (my jar on the shelf is over a year now).

The hyssop I get is from Jordan. I also receive sumac and the blend zaatar.